# how to use a random on a certain column by using dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data which will be printed in a random order but i want to perform the random operation on a perticular column
**The input data will be like this:**

```
Asset_Id    Asset Family         Asset Name Location    Asset Component     
1           Haptic Analyser      HAL1       Zenoa       Tetris Measuring Unit   
2           Haptic Analyser      HAL2       Zenoa       Micro Pressure Platform 
3           Hyperdome Inspector  HISP1      Technopolis Laser Column            
4           Nano Dial Assembler  NDA11      Zen         Fusion Tank
5           Nano Dial Assembler1 NDA12      goa         Fusion Tank1
6           Nano Dial Assembler2 NDA13      Technopolis Fusion Tank2
7           Nano Dial Assembler3 NDA14      goa         Fusion Tank3
```

**In This input i want to apply the random operation on column "Location"   other will be printed same as it is..**

for this i have written a code :
**This will read the csv file and print all row/column in random order**

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\rahul\\Desktop\\Data_Manufacturing.csv")
ds = df.sample(frac=1)
print(ds)
```

But i want to apply the random operation on particular column not whole csv file
for that i have tried to access a column and get the random vaues but its not correct i guess:
**This will get column "Location" values**

```
df.iloc[:, [1]]
```

i tried to put in this way to get random values:

```
df.iloc[np.random.choice(df.index, 5),[:, [1]]
```

i know its not correct please tell me how to get it how do i get a particular column in a random order...any help will be appreciable..Thank you

Comment: I am a little confused on what the expected output would be, but have you tried `df['Location'].sample(frac=1)`  If that is not your desired output, then can you please add a sample output of what your end goal will be for this piece of code.

Comment: i got it.... thnx a lot

Comment: @jtweeder sir I have one more doubt that want to print it with whole column means-- When i use "ds = df.sample(frac=1)" it will shuffle all the row and print it but i want another operation in that after  getting all random data my column(Location) will also be shuffle

Comment: @jtweeder  I want to merge this both lines "ds = df.sample(frac=1)" and df['Location'].sample(frac=1) so i can get both all column in random order and one certain column in random order